# Why there are three functions for robust M-Estimators

Tags: regression, machine-learning, m-estimation

I have spent a lot of time reading about Robust regression, especially M- estimators and their related functions (objective function, score function, and weight function). I know that M-estimators have high relative efficiency and low breakdown points.

My question is

Why each M- estimate has three functions?

[image: Equations of weight functions]
[image: Graphs of weight functions 2]

Because I understand that the objective function is the one we should care about. This means when I want to develop a new robust regression, I should only think about creating a new objective function.

Comment: by three functions are you talking about the influence function being one of them, or some specific class of M-estimator like GM-, R-, S-estimators that go through several steps in-between to reach a final result

Comment: Yes, score function = influence function

Answer (score 3):

The objective function is the M estimator and in the ML setting is called robust loss function. The m estimator estimates the estimated parameter in the problem. Score function which is called influence function is the first derivative of objective function and it tells if residuals' value change how much m estimator (loss function) changes. in the robust perspective there shouldn't be significant changes in m estimator (loss function). There are many different estimator as you mentioned. So one way to compare different estimators is to see which one has small changes in its influence function. Another way to look at how an m estimator works is to see the weight function behavior. The weight function is the second derivative of m estimator(loss function). It is also first derivative of Influence function. Like Influence function, it tells if the residuals value change how much the influence function changes. Again, small changes are acceptable from a robust perspective.